# Remove Database Dependency from Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

What I am trying to accomplish is having an uploader and model without requiring the image field to be saved into the database.

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  def store_dir
    "#{default_path}"
  end

  version :mobile do
    process :resize_to_fit => [118,110]
  end

end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  attr_acccessible :image

end
```

I've read this: http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/04/using-carrierwave-without-orm.html but think there is a better way.

What I was thinking was doing a before_save and removing the image value from the object, but still feels like such a hack.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible while using carrierwave. Carrierwave requires you to mount uploader and when an uploader is mounted, the column for image is created in database.